# Context filtering in Solr Auto Suggester is not working

Tags: solr, ofbiz

I am using Solr 6.3 version, I am trying to implement auto suggester in which I need to apply context filter. I have used 'AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory' for lookupImplementation and 'DocumentDictionaryFactory' for dictionaryImpl and applied the filter on document type 'Product'.  But, it does not work for me.

Here is the sample code for the same:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
      <str name="field">productName</str>
      <str name="contextField">documentType</str>
      <str name="weightField"></str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">lowercase</str>
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

Request Handler :

```
<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler"
              startup="lazy" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="suggest">true</str>
      <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Query:

```
/suggest&df=productName&cfq=Product&suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&suggest.q=cap
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter is named `suggest.cfq` (like the other parameters to the suggest module), not just plain `cfq`.